# Create a JSON string in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to create JSON string of below format for the flot charts. I am stuck here

```
[{ "label" : "Name"
   "data" : [[],[],[],[]]
}]


var day = ["sun", "mon", "tue", "wed"];
var data = [];
for(var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
 var innerData = [];
 innerData.push(day[i], value[i]);
 data.push(innerData);
}
```

I am a little confused creating the json string with my code. can someone help me with this. I am doing something wrong to achieve what i am looking for ?

Comment: What is your ouput now? Can you give us some more information?

Comment: Incomplet question …

Comment: Which part of this are your confuse about?

Comment: The variable `value` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: I am confused with the output, when i see the console.log all is `[Array[2], Array[2]...]` and when i do the strigify and send it to the chart, the chart does not pick the string

Comment: What do you want to do ?

Comment: @Md.Yusuf I want to create the JSON String in the given format. What am i doing wrong in my code and my flot chart is not picking the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some changes.

```
var v = [{ "label": "Name",
            "data" : []
          }];
var days = ["sun","mon","tue","wed"];
var values = [4,7,3,5];
for ( var i = 0; i < values.length; i+= 1) {
     v[0].data.push([ days[i],values[i]]);
}
console.log(v);
```

See it in action  [here](http://jsbin.com/zeqad/1/edit?html,console)